# collapsing technique in relational database

Tags: database-design, denormalization

I am new to Database Design. And i am confused with Collapsing technique in database.

Example:  Consider the following Many-to-Many relation between “Project” and “Developer”:

Each project is assigned many developers and each developer may be assigned many projects at the same time.

```
          PROJECT            IS  ASSSIGNED TO           DEVELOPER
```

Project, Developer are 2 entities.  Please let me know how to implement collapsing technique for this.

Regards
Vikram

Answer (score 0):

For many-to-many relationships you normally use a third entity like this:

```
PROJECT (project_id, project_name)
ASSIGNMENT (project_id, developer_id)
DEVELOPER (developer_id, developer_name)
```

So technically (in a physical model) it's equivalent one-to-many relationship between project and assignment and another one-to-many between developer and assignment:

```
PROJECT -----< ASSIGNMENT >----- DEVELOPER
```